# Is there possibility that there is error information which wasn't printed to screen in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

My question goes like this:

I need to get a numerical integral in every loop. 
Because of the numerical method, there maybe errors, like failure of convergence in certain number of iterations.
So, I want to record the loops in which errors happen by the function "Check"().

As shown in following picture, every list shows the loops in which errors happen so far.

As you can see, in the 86th loop, there is an error information, so "86" was appended to error list.
In the 84th loop, no error information was output to the screen, however, "84" was appended to error list.
my question is why this happened? Is there possibility that there is error information which wasn't printed to screen in the 84th loop?

[image]

Part of my code is:

```
(*ndist and gdist are functions of two distributions. errk is used to store the loop number if error happens in current loop. errklist is used to store all loops in which error happens so far.*)
errk =  Flatten[Check[
nentropy = NIntegrate[ndist Log[ndist], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
gentropy = NIntegrate[gdist Log[gdist], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}],Sow[k]] // Reap // Rest];           
AppendTo[errklist, (j - 1)*101 + errk];
```

Comment: Are you sure that 84 was appended to the error list _right after_ you set `k=84` and not before?

Comment: And _maybe_ Mathematica is talking about a different kind of error for `k=86`

Comment: save the offending input state and do the integrals outside the loop to see whats going on.

Comment: @polfosol yes i am sure

Comment: @agentp as you say, when do the integrals outside the loop, error information is printed to screen.  So why? thank you

Comment: that message you see is not generated by `NIntegrate`, but later when you try to `BinaryWrite` the result.